# TableView cell 0 index error

Tags: iphone, uitableview, button

I have four buttons on a UITableViewCell of 0 index.I have set tag for the buttons like 0,1,2,3.
When I am setting the selected property to NO on the button of 0 tag it shows the following error:

```
-[UITableView set Selected:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

But there is no error for other buttons:

the code is here:

```
    UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[tableView viewWithTag:0];
    [button1 setSelected:NO];
    UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[tableView viewWithTag:2];
    [button2 setSelected:NO];
    UIButton *button3 = (UIButton *)[tableView viewWithTag:3];
    [button3 setSelected:NO];
    [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [button3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Edited code:

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
     UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
     NSLog(@"hi...%d",clickedButtonPath.row);
    if(theButton.tag==0)
    {
        theButton.selected=YES;
        [theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
         UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:1];
        [button1 setSelected:NO];
        UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:2];
        [button2 setSelected:NO];
        UIButton *button3 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:3];
        [button3 setSelected:NO];
        [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    }
    else if(theButton.tag==1)
    {
        theButton.selected=YES;
        [theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:0];
        [button1 setSelected:NO];
        UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:2];
        [button2 setSelected:NO];
        UIButton *button3 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:3];
        [button3 setSelected:NO];
        [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else if(theButton.tag==2)
    {
        theButton.selected=YES;
        [theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:0];
        [button1 setSelected:NO];
        UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:1];
        [button2 setSelected:NO];
        UIButton *button3 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:3];
        [button3 setSelected:NO];
        [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }

    else if(theButton.tag==3)
    {
        theButton.selected=YES;
        [theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:0];
        [button1 setSelected:NO];
        UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:2];
        [button2 setSelected:NO];
        UIButton *button3 = (UIButton *)[clickedCell viewWithTag:1];
        [button3 setSelected:NO];
        [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[UITableViewCellContentView setSelected():] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6828f20
```

Full code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tablView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    subviewArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tablView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    for(UIView *eachView in [cell.contentView subviews])
        [eachView removeFromSuperview];

    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:187.0/255.0 green:184.0/255.0 blue:229.0/255.0 alpha:1] autorelease]];
   // [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        UILabel *lbldoorwidth=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [lbldoorwidth setText:@"Door Width"];
        [lbldoorwidth setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [lbldoorwidth setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [lbldoorwidth setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 200, 50)];
        UIView *underline=[[UIView alloc]init];
        [underline setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [underline setFrame:CGRectMake(100,40,88, 2)];

        UIButton *option1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [option1 setFrame:CGRectMake(8,50,20,20)];
        [option1 setTag:0];
        [option1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [option1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [option1 addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        // UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"];
        //[option1 setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-on.png"];
        //[option1 setImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];


        UILabel *option1Label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [option1Label setFrame:CGRectMake(38,45,30,30)];
        [option1Label setText:@"30\""];
        [option1Label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UIButton *option2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [option2 setFrame:CGRectMake(78,50,20,20)];
        [option2 setTag:1];
        [option2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [option2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [option2 addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        UILabel *option2Label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [option2Label setFrame:CGRectMake(108,45,30,30)];
        [option2Label setText:@"32\""];
        [option2Label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UIButton *option3=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [option3 setFrame:CGRectMake(148,50,20,20)];
        [option3 setTag:2];
        [option3 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [option3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [option3 addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



        UILabel *option3Label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [option3Label setFrame:CGRectMake(178,45,30,30)];
        [option3Label setText:@"34\""];
        [option3Label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UIButton *option4=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [option4 setFrame:CGRectMake(218,50,20,20)];
        [option4 setTag:3];
        [option4 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [option4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [option4 addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UILabel *option4Label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [option4Label setFrame:CGRectMake(248,45,30,30)];
        [option4Label setText:@"36\""];
        [option4Label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbldoorwidth];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:underline];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:option1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:option1Label];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:option2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:option2Label];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:option3];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:option3Label];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:option4];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:option4Label];

}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: you are not using reusable tableview cell, its non reusable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access your button like this

```
 UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:0];  


UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
```

Comment: I am not sure whether the code is working or not, as its not showing any error. The edited code is pasted above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20740/discussion-between-kittu88-and-rajneesh071)